# Using Sublime to edit Yocto files, leads to fail to start bitbake server

Tags: sublimetext3, yocto

If I open my Yocto project's folder with [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) under Ubuntu 16.04 and try to build with:

```
bitbake <image>
```

I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to start bitbake server (None)
ERROR: Server log for this session (/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1-sw25v00/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
--- Starting bitbake server pid 4602 at 2020-02-01 02:59:00.519051 ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/daemonize.py", line 83, in createDaemon
    function()
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/server/process.py", line 469, in _startServer
    self.cooker = bb.cooker.BBCooker(self.configuration, self.featureset)
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.initConfigurationData()
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 396, in initConfigurationData
    self.add_filewatch(mc.getVar("__base_depends", False), self.configwatcher)
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 306, in add_filewatch
    watcher.add_watch(f, self.watchmask, quiet=False)
  File "/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/pyinotify.py", line 1924, in add_watch
    raise WatchManagerError(err, ret_)
pyinotify.WatchManagerError: add_watch: cannot watch /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1-sw25v00/conf WD=-1, Errno=No space left on device (ENOSPC)
ERROR: No space left on device or exceeds fs.inotify.max_user_watches?
ERROR: To check max_user_watches: sysctl -n fs.inotify.max_user_watches.
ERROR: To modify max_user_watches: sysctl -n -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=<value>.
ERROR: Root privilege is required to modify max_user_watches.
```

Closing the editor and issue again the command works correctly.
Other editors (like `gedit`) does not have this behavior.

I know I can live without `Sublime`, but I want to understand che cause of the errors.

Comment: According to error message, you have no more space.

Comment: Please read the question. It's not true. I have 122G free on `/` and 265G free on `/home`. If I close Sublime, all works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running out of `inotify` watches. Software such as Sublime and the program you're running here (among others) use `inotify` watches to detect changes to the file system, such as being able to track when files are changing or when the contents of a directory changes.

There's a (user settable) upper limit to the number of watches that can be in use at once, and the rather cryptic error message you're seeing here is a symptom of the limit being reached and the program failing to obtain a watch.

The default value for the maximum `inotify` watches may not be set high enough on your system for the software (and volume of files) that you're using, but you can change that if you like.

The output at the bottom of your error diagnotic information shows how you can view/adjust the upper limit. The following question also shows how you could do this as well.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached